# .Net Core API Reject Incomplete JSON Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

**I need to reject the Request if the body has incomplete JSON.**

I have a .NetCore API, which has a lot of properties. That API does a lot of operations and will be getting a lot of requests, so want to reject if the JSON is incomplete beforehand.

If, I have below AssignmentDetail class,

```
public class AssignmentDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Complete JSON Example**

```
{
     "Name":"dfsdfsdf", 
     "Address":"essdfsdfsd", 
}
```

**Incomplete JSON Example**

```
{
     "Name":"dfsdfsdf" 
}
```

I have some approaches but need something which can be done through in startup, but just for that action.

1. Using custom Serializable for that AssignmentDetail model **(Don't want this approach)**
2. Creating a function to validate the Incomplete JSON like validateIncompleteJSON() **(Don't want this approach)**
3. **Something in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) but just for that controller action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ProcessAssignment")]
    public async Task<AssignmentResponseModel> ProcessAssignment(AssignmentDetail model)
    {
        var response = new AssignmentResponseModel();
        try
        {
            //can call function here to check the incomlpete JSON 
            //validateIncompleteJSON();


            //var result = await _mediator.Send(queryDetails);
            //response = result.Response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        return response;
    }
```

I don't want to use the Serializable way, as the class is too big and will have to handle all the properties.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "incomplete JSON"?

Comment: @IanKemp I have edited the question to explain, what I mean by Incomplete JSON. Thanks. I hope, it explains what I meant.

Comment: @Pratik Bhoir Only adding a  [Required] attribute is also unacceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Data Annotations add Required Attribute to property**

> Codes of Model

```
public class AssignmentDetail
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

> Codes of Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/ProcessAssignment")]
    public IActionResult ProcessAssignment(AssignmentDetail model)
    {
        //var response = new AssignmentResponseModel();
        //try
        //{
        //    //can call function here to check the incomlpete JSON 
        //    //validateIncompleteJSON();


        //    //var result = await _mediator.Send(queryDetails);
        //    //response = result.Response;
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    throw exception;
        //}
        //return response;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok("Success");
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```